# Can I merge two conversation threads in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, gmail-conversations

I really like that gmail keeps related email messages in one "thread" for easy access. But sometimes an email message gets left out. (I suspect the senders email client is misbehaving.)

Is there a way to tell Gmail that I want this email message to belong to an ongoing conversation?

Comment: Another 24 months on and still no progress. I suggest everyone on here 'report' this issue by following the following link; https://support.google.com/mail/bin/static.py?hl=en&page=known_issues.cs In the "Composing and Reading Mail" section there is "Messages are improperly threaded" item:
"At this time, you can't manually merge or separate messages from conversations." Click "Report" and this will hopefully keep this issue in the forefront of Google's minds. Cheers!

Comment: Tim's comment is the best we can do for now. Thanks for the link, @Tim.

Comment: If I could checkbox a pile of client emails and merge them all together, that would make invoicing easier.  So it's not just a "conversation" issue--a timer-saver too.

Comment: @user24126 your link (https://support.google.com/mail/bin/static.py?hl=en&page=known_issues.cs) no longer displays the issue you mentioned. Does anybody have a new link for the issue user24126 mentioned?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

No, there isn't. You can mute a thread, but you can't cleanly merge them.

One thing you can do: forward an orphaned email to yourself as a response to the thread you want it to be a part of, then delete the original. That won't force your sender to keep things together, nor is it particularly automated, but for reading/archiving purposes it may fit your needs.

Comment: by forward you mean copy-paste?

Comment: Mail 1:- subject :- Nayana Group Invoice on this we have 3 conversation with